# How to count number of digit-asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have a textbox that user can enter a number in it.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox_NationalCode" runat="server" Width ="100%"></asp:TextBox>
```

and :

```
string code=TextBox_NationalCode.text
```

I want to count number of digits in "code". Eg: user enters 123456789 and I have the number of digits = 9

Comment: You have to at least try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int count = code.Count(Char.IsDigit);
```